# how to fix permission behavior of www folder

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server

I'm working in the `www` directory of apache. I need to do this because other people in my company need to see my work constantly - whether to access updated versions of things I'm working on (mostly css files) or to give me feedback (this is all on a local network).

I'm working with a live build of the latest Ubuntu 14.04, with Apache 2.2. And the permission system is giving me a headache. Mostly this is due to the surprising inconsistency when working with the `www` directory - sometimes I can access everything, sometimes I can access them but can't copy to other places, sometimes some directories are inaccessible. I think the last update presented more weird limitations that didn't exist before.

I always work around this somehow. Either I `sudo cp` through command line, or I do `sudo nautilus` or I change the permissions for a limited period of time (apache needs the permissions to be for `www-data`, else when you try to access the site through `localhost` the site receives a `403` for all its static files).

But I've had enough, this is ridiculous. I need that directory to behave as if I own it, but not have any clash with Apache.

I can find a lot of answers around this site about permission problems, but like I said - I don't have a problem solving this temporarily. But I'm looking to understand **what's the right way to work with the www directory**, without breaking anything and without having to sudo every little thing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, keeping the directories' owned by `root` would be fine.  What I prefer is, create a group say `www-editor` and make yourself (and any other co-editors) member of the group.  `chgrp` the `www` folder to `www-editor` and grant full permission to the group.

By default, the `www-editor` group should have write permission to the folders, and files newly written should have similar permissions.  It would be handy to turn the sticky bit on for `www` and all subdirectories (i.e. `sudo chmod g+s www`).

In that way, any files you created will be owned by you (not `root` as `sudo` not required) and owned by group `www-editor`.  A sample of `ls -l` on directory `www` will look like:

```
drwxrwsr-x  8 root    www-editor 4096 Feb 28 00:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root    root       4096 Mar 16 10:14 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 ken_l   www-editor 1150 Feb  8  2013 favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r--  1 root    www-editor  177 Dec 25  2012 index.html
drwxrwsr-x  2 ken_l   www-editor 4096 Jun 12  2013 main
```

From the example above, `ken_l` created `index.html` and copied `favicon.ico` to `www` without `sudo`.

Permissions for `www-data` should be minimized to reduce security risks.  Therefore directories should, by default, read-only by others (including `www-data`).  Of course you can always fine tune permissions of specific directories as needed.

Comment: If root is the right way to go it's fine by me. The problem is when I need to move things around, delete or copy certain files, etc. (as one does constantly during development), I hit a brick wall every time and need to do some workaround. I have to have some flexibility for development, but also serve the site locally using apache at the same time. And I can't find any setup that fits that description

Comment: the idea is not to use root specifically. As Ken explains, you need to create a group that has permissions similar to root permissions, but only for the www folder. THen, make your normal user account a member of the new group. This will allow you to copy files, etc without needing to use sudo or su.

Comment: @Jonathan clarified my point. I edited my answer to include an illustration to what I meant.

Comment: By the way, after adding yourself to `www-editor` group, you will need to logout/login to refresh group permission with commands:
`sudo su - www-editor` > $ `id` > $ `exit`

Comment: It's been months. I don't remember what I did eventually, but looking back I have no idea why I didn't mark your answer as correct, as it is obviously (in retrospect anyway) what I was looking for